# Persistent url parameter through session

Tags: javascript, url, query-string, url-parameters

I managed to add a new parameter to the url query string (not sure if my method is perfect).

But I would like to make it **persistent through the session**.

Here is the code to retrieve the referrer domain name and add it as parameter :

```
function addRefererParam () {
var ref = document.referrer;  //Get Referrer
var refDomain = ref.match(/[^(?:http:\/\/|www\.|https:\/\/)]([^\/]+)/i)[0]; //Extract Referrer Domain name for better readability

  if (refDomain.match(/mydomain|null|undefined/i)) { //check if domain not null or own domain. 
    return location.search;
} else {
    return location.search += "utm_source=" + refDomain; //create new query string with referrer domain
}
}
```

**Notes:**

I am aware of the cookie method or "sessionStorage" but I want to pass the value of the parameter to an iframe from another domain, so it does not seem to work in that  case.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: How to make a query string persistent through a session. For now, the parameter does not remain if I visit another page.